# Unable to cast object of type 'Model.Entities' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

MVC3 EF5. It's running well. But when I update model from database, builds successfully but I got the exception above on the last line. When I last updated from database it was 2-3 months ago, and it was fine.

```
 public static ObjectContext GetContext()
 {
     Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
     Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Model.Entities");
     return (ObjectContext)Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
 }
```

Comment: As the error says, you can't cast a `Model.Entities` to an `ObjectContext`. It's not clear what you're trying to do, so it's hard to say much more than that.

Comment: I took over the project. I don't have a clue either. When I update from database, final step of the wizard says "your project references an older version of entity framework". Makes sense?

Comment: Sounds like you need to quite a bit more research into the application and figure out what's supposed to be happening in this code. Out of context it makes little sense.

Comment: What I am really wondering is, how it works fine unless update the model from database.

Comment: Looks like EF was upgraded without updating the model. Now when you do update the model, a `DbContext` is created. Maybe you're OK if you create and return a `DbContext`. However, it's really weird to return an `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`) in the first place. In EF you're supposed to create context classes *inheriting* from `DbContext`, and it looks like `Model.Entities` is one.

Comment: Yes. "Entities" is inherited from DbContext. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Just return a `Model.Entities()` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Entity Framework provide `DbContext`, as opposed to the `ObjectContext` that was <= EF 4.0. However, it is still possible to return a reference to the `ObjectContext` via [`IObjectContextAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

```
 Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Model.Entities");
 var entities = (DbContext)(Activator.CreateInstance(calcType));
 return ((IObjectContextAdapter)entities).ObjectContext;
```

Personally however, I would instead look at upgrading your code to return the `DbContext`, as it is more advanced.